# Why is the reverse aldol cleavage of fructose 1,6-bisphosphate highly endergonic under standard conditions?

Tags: thermodynamics, biochemistry, free-energy, aldol-reaction

I have another question similar to [this one](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/149706/why-is-the-formation-of-a-peptide-bond-not-spontaneous/149711#149711).  I just don't have intuition for why reactions are thermodynamically favorable or unfavorable and I'd like to build it.  This time I'd like to ask about the reverse aldol reaction $$\ce{Fructose-1,6-Bisphosphate -> Dihydroxyacetone Phosphate + Glyceraldehyde-3-Phosphate}$$

The standard free energy of this reaction is [+23.8 kJ/mol](https://iubmb.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1016/0307-4412%2881%2990102-3).[1]

I was hoping someone could help me understand why.  The larger molecule has lower entropy and charge-charge repulsion.  Why is it so thermodynamically unfavorable for it to break apart?

[1]
Cornish-Bowden, A. Thermodynamic Aspects of Glycolysis. *Biochem. Educ.* 1981, *9* (4), 133–137.

Comment: Take a look at the bonds being formed and broken. That difference in enthalpy overwhelms the entropic consideration.